# Replace certain records in a column with given condition in kdb

Tags: replace, kdb

I have a table below:

```
tab:([]a:(`$"1-01";`2;`$"3-01";`4;`$"5-01";`6);source:`a`a`b`b`a`b)

a    source
-----------
1-01 a     
2    a     
3-01 b     
4    b     
5-01 a     
6    b
```

I would like to change the 1-01 and 5-01 back to 1 but not for 3-01 depending on the source. I wrote the code below:

```
`$({ssr[string x;"-01";""]}each tab[`a])
```

by doing this I can put this back to a column, but this is not what I want. I also did the following:

```
`$({ssr[string x;"-01";""]}each tab[`a] where source=`a)
```

but after doing this I do not know how to put it back to the table. Then I thought of using execution control: but not sure how i should code it. I have it half way done and it does not really work:

```
?[tab[`source] = `a;`$({ssr[string tab[`a];"-01";""]});tab[`a]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "update" seems to be what you need:

```
q)update `$ssr[;"-01";""] each string a from tab where source=`a
a    source
-----------
1    a
2    a
3-01 b
4    b
5    a
6    b
```

Comment: thanks,do you know why i can't use update in a funciton? there is always an error. I had to use another select statement to include this.

Comment: Can you give an example of the update in a function?

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work.    update  a:`$({ssr[string x;"-01";""]}each tab[`a]) from `tab;

Comment: That exact line works for me inside a function. {update a:\`$({ssr[string x;"-01";""]}each tab[\`a]) from \`tab}[]

Comment: thats weird.   if i don't do `tab it works inside a big function. but if i use `tab it doesnt work

Comment: Putting a backtick in front of the table name specifies that it is a global table. In my example, tab is defined globally (outside of the scope of that function). In your case, you must have defined tab only within the scope of that function, making it a local

Comment: so local u can't update table by using backtick? u have to redefine it again? thanks

Comment: Correct. If local, you can run the update (without the backtick on the table name) and then assign the result back to the table name again. For example: {tab:([]col1:\`a\`b\`c;col2:1 2 3);tab:update col2:99 from tab;tab}[]

Comment: ok thanks! that explains why sometimes i can update and sometimes i cant!